# PHP AJAX Countdown Timer

Tags: php, ajax

I'm looking to use this countdown timer

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

but I need it to countdown until a specific time from a time entered in a MySQL database. The time is in 23:00:00 format

Here is what I have so far. Just don't know how to plug the time into the JavaScript.

```
<?php

include('function.php');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lockpick WHERE date= CURDATE()");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($data);
$EndTime = $row['EndTime'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var austDay = new Date();
        austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
        $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden div and load your PHP var into it on pageload. Call it something like #countTo - set it to display:none; in the CSS so it isn't visible.

Access the contents of that div with:

```
var countTo = document.getElementById("countTo").innerHTML;
```

Then you can use it all you want!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider getting value using ajax call.
If you do not want to do that you can get value of end time like that

```
    <script>
        var endTime = <?php 
        include('function.php');
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lockpick WHERE date= CURDATE()");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($data);
        echo $row['EndTime'];
        ?>;
..continue script
    </script>
```